# Need a test case where given code for minimum number of coins fails in python?

Tags: python, function, optimization, python-2.7

Here is the code to calculate change for given amount:
However, it was not written to give minimum no of coins for the change amount, yet the code seems to give minimum required number of coins. I want a case where it fails to give minimum no of coins required.

```
def change(amount):
    money = ()
    for coin in [25,10,5,1]:
        num = amount/coin
        money += (coin,) * num
        amount -= coin * num

    return money

print change(59)

output is: 
(25, 25, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: What makes you think it might not give minimum number of coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Greedy_method), for that set of possible coins the greedy algorithm will always return the optimal result. However, *"[...] if the coin denominations were 1, 3 and 4, then to make 6, the greedy algorithm would choose three coins (4,1,1) whereas the optimal solution is two coins (3,3)"*.

Therefore, you'd need to change the set of possible coins to face a non-optimal solution with that algorithm.

Comment: Thus, the question code is optimal for the current case of change coins (denominations)?

Comment: thats exactly what I was expecting..

Comment: @user1988876, if so you asked a question with no possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated, the greedy solution works for that set of coins.

An example of an optimal algorithm, which works for all sets of coins:

```
coins = (1, 5, 10, 25)

def change(amount):
    min_coins = [()]
    for i in range(1, amount+1):
        best = min((min_coins[i-x] + (x,) for x in coins if i >= x), key=len)
        min_coins.append(best)
    return min_coins[amount]

print change(59)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the desired outcome of the test case literally, a negative number can cause it to fail to give the minimum number of coins required.

```
print change(-1)
(10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: What is the minimum # of coins required in this case?

Comment: Good question.  An IOU?  I guess one would expect the answer to be -1.